# Can I access the service definition for the web service for a specific SharePoint list?

Tags: list, web-services, wsdl

I have a problem accessing the web service ?wsdl for SharePoint lists, although I can see the list of operations.

For example, for the following URLS:

```
http://team/sites/test/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx - returns a list of operations
http://team/sites/test/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL - returns the wsdl document


http://team/sites/test/Lists/TestList1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx - returns a list of operations
http://team/sites/test/Lists/TestList1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL - returns a 404 error (example of full error pasted below).
```

I've checked on a few SP installations and I'm seeing the same behaviour on all of them, I've also tried logging on to the web server as admin and calling the pages and I get the same result each time. I've also checked that DisableLoopbackCheck is set to 1 in the registry.

Is it the case that there is no WSDL available for specific lists, just for the generic list type i.e. you get the WSDL from `<root>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL` and access the actual service via `<root>/<Lists>/<MyList>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`, or have I got the wrong end of the stick here? Do lists have web services all of their own at all?

Any help gratefuly accepted.

---   ---   ---   Error Text  ---   ---   ---

```
There was an error downloading 'http://team/sites/test/Lists/Repairs%20Services%20Customer%20Satisfaction%20TEST/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://team/sites/test/Lists/Repairs Services Customer Satisfaction TEST/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. There is no WSDL available for specific lists. All the operations on the Lists web service are performed against the local SPWeb and take a ListName as a parameter.

Comment: +1, I would add that @Tim is probably looking for the [Lists.GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist(v=office.12).aspx) method which @MBSurf hinted at.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that MBsurf - this was a question which came from another team who were trying to access the contents of a SP list. I've made a little demo in C# to show them how to access the list they want and get the contents back.

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have changed the Class name properly in asmx file

Also check for certificates in your server if u don' have 1 create a new certificate and do the whole process again.....

hope it will help